# Sencha Touch theming: how are active/selected colors calculated from $base-color?

Tags: sencha-touch, sass, sencha-touch-2

I did set the `$base-color` of my application to `#000000`, using Sencha Touch 2.3.1 and the default theme.

List selections, picker bars and other "active elements" are displayed in colors that range from pink to red.

I would like to have all those elements gray instead. Is there an alternative way of changing these, other than going through the whole app to find the relevant classes?
I guess it would be nice to have a `$secondary-color` variable that could be switched to control those, does such a variable exist?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're possibly looking for `$active-color` variable

Comment: In my application I actually had to change `$active-color`, `$list-pressed-color` and override the `.x-picker-bar`. I guess the answer to my question is that there isn't a magic variable to change all at once.